# How to append a numpy array to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm trying to append a 3x2 numpy array to an existing dataframe. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.Dataframe({"A": [0,0,0], "B": [1,1,1]})
arr = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)

df[["C", "D"]] = arr  # NOPE!
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) while converting your array to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["C", "D"])], axis=1)
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1
1  0  1  2  3
2  0  1  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because you need to pass a df:

```
arr = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2))

df[["C", "D"]] = arr #YEP

#Output
    A   B   C   D

0   0   1   0   1

1   0   1   2   3

2   0   1   4   5
```